# Boost block indirect sort segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, boost, parallel-processing

Following is the code:

```
template<int N>
void para_sort(std::vector<bfs_node<N>>& res) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        boost::sort::block_indirect_sort(res.begin(), res.end(), compare_node<N>);
    }
}
```

The code runs without any exception when running with only one OMP thread.
However, the code throws in an exception on running with multiple threads.

The code works fine with multiple threads when `Boost::Parallel_stable_sort` used.

I suspected it would be the strict weak ordering requirement that caused it raise exception. But in that case it should be raised with `parallel_stable_sort` and `std::sort` (sequential version).

Does `boost::block_indirect_sort` demands more stricter or weaker ordering constraint?

```
template<int N>
bool compare_node(const bfs_node<N>& lhs, const bfs_node<N>& rhs) {
    if (lhs.id == rhs.id) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N * 64; ++i) {
        bool lflag = in_set(lhs.id, i);
        bool rflag = in_set(rhs.id, i);
        if (lflag == rflag ) { continue; }
        if (lflag) return true;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
} //
```

where `id` field here represents a `unordered_set` type data structure.
For ex: `id` represents the set `{1,2,3}`
and `in_set(id, 1)`  will return `true` and otherwise `false`

Exception raised:
`Invalid read of size 16
==2125==    at 0x46C59F: void boost::sort::pdqsort_detail::pdqsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<bfs_node<1>*, std::vector<bfs_node<1>, std::allocator<bfs_node<1> > > >, std::less<bfs_node<1> >, false>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<bfs_node<1>*, std::vector<bfs_node<1>, std::allocator<bfs_node<1> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<bfs_node<1>*, std::vector<bfs_node<1>, std::allocator<bfs_node<1> > > >, std::less<bfs_node<1> >, int, bool)`

Comment: Are you setting the number of threads with an additional argument to `block_indirect_sort`? Do you need the OMP directive if so?

Comment: I tried so with no effect. `#pragma omp parallel` so should expose all threads to be used.